# Is list comprehension always safe?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am working with Python3 and I was wondering that if list comprehension is always safe.

For instance:

```
mylist = ["string1", "string2", "foo", "bar"]
# I want to remove all items with "string" substring:
pattern_to_rm = "string"
mylist = [ item for item in mylist if pattern_to_rm not in item ]
# print(mylist) = ["foo", "bar"]
```

Can I have some issues with this way (as I am changing the input list size while iterating)? Do I have to make a copy or something? `mylist` will never be a huge list, but contains very important data.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does not change the list size while iterating. It builds a new list from the filtered items and then reassigns the `mylist` reference to the new list. This is safe, and you don't need to make a copy or anything.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and important information!